# Error validating SAML response with spring security

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I'm using spring security saml in an application to implement sso.
I 'm getting the following exception when validating SAML response:

```
2016-12-26 17:33:48,072 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Creating XMLSignature object
2016-12-26 17:33:48,072 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512
2016-12-26 17:33:48,072 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Signature validated with key from supplied credential
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
2016-12-26 17:33:48,088 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine] Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials
2016-12-26 17:33:48,089 DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine] Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials
2016-12-26 17:33:48,089 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] Validation of authentication statement in assertion failed, skipping
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature is not trusted or invalid
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:272)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at
```

Any ideas please about the cause of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: where do you store this signature? I don't think spring saml uses a default keystore, so you need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks Tina
I'm using the same certificate as my signer (the same certif is used also for encryption/Decryption).
I'm not facing a problem with encryption/Decryption, only validating the siganture is causing a problem.